# Text editor that can paste lines

Tags: text-editor

Is there any text editor that can paste the selected lines?

For example I select 10 lines, then, when I use paste, it will paste the first 5 lines with the next 5 lines, separated with a tab.

I am using Windows but I can install Linux in VirtualBox to try a Linux text editor if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There is a linux command-line tool `paste`. Perhaps it can do what you want. (So `paste` not really an editor. It rather operates on text files, or text input.)

```
NAME
       paste - merge lines of files

SYNOPSIS
       paste [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       Write lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines
       from each FILE, separated by TABs, to standard output.
```

Typically you combine `paste` together with `cat`, `comm`, `join`, `cut` `head` and `tail`.

Comment: I am using paste on Windows - I am using GnuWin32. However it would be quite useful to have a paste option in an editor

Answer (score 1):

If you use [CudaText](https://cudatext.github.io/) editor, it's easy to write a plugin in Python, and call it "Paste 2", then you can call it from "Plugins / Paste 2" menu. Plugin can take the clipboard contents, and insert tab-char into it, and do the insertion with that tab-char.